# Send blob data to node using fetch, multer, express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api, multer

Trying to send a blob object to my node server. On the client side I'm recording some audio using MediaRecorder and then I want to send the file to my server for processing.

```
      saveButton.onclick = function(e, audio) {
        var blobData = localStorage.getItem('recording');
        console.log(blobData);

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('upl', blobData, 'blobby.raw');

        fetch('/api/test',
          {
            method: 'post',
            body: fd
          })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('done');
          return response;
        })
        .catch(function(err){ 
          console.log(err);
        });

      }
```

This is my express route, which uses multer:

```
  var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/../public/uploads/' });
  var type = upload.single('upl');
  app.post('/api/test', type, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
    // do stuff with file
  });
```

But my logs return nothing:

```
{ upl: '' }
undefined
```

Been spending a long time on this so any help appreciated!

Comment: Part of multer ```var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/../public/uploads/' });
var type = upload.single('upl');```

Comment: Do you get anything if you try to send just a regular string instead of `blobData`, and what does the `console.log(blobData)`  tell you.

Comment: What `Content-Type` header does the browser send if you view the fetch network request from your browser's web dev tools?

Comment: after changing to string it still outputs: `{ upl: '' }`

Comment: blobData is an object ```Blob {size: 6937, type: "audio/wav"}
size
:
6937
type
:
"audio/wav"
__proto__
:
Blob```

Comment: Generally you'd get strings back from localStorage, but clearly the fetch or append is failing

Comment: Under request headers I get `content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryuXIvVIjDViONFgyd`

Comment: Request payload: `------WebKitFormBoundaryuXIvVIjDViONFgyd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upl"


------WebKitFormBoundaryuXIvVIjDViONFgyd--`

Comment: Perhaps I should be using another method? I have multer working for a normal HTML form post with manually uploaded files rather than on-the-fly recording

Comment: You could try to add  headers: {  
       "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"  
    } to your fetch options

Comment: Makes no difference @MichaelTroger

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was just able to run a minimum configuration of your above example and it worked fine for me.

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')); // for serving the HTML file

var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads/' });
var type = upload.single('upl');

app.post('/api/test', type, function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.file);
   // do stuff with file
});

app.listen(3000);
```

HTML file in `public`:

```
<script>
var myBlob = new Blob(["This is my blob content"], {type : "text/plain"});
console.log(myBlob);

// here unnecessary - just for testing if it can be read from local storage
localStorage.myfile = myBlob;

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('upl', localStorage.myfile, 'blobby.txt');

fetch('/api/test',
{
    method: 'post',
    body: fd
}); 
</script>
```

The `console.log(myBlob);` on the frontend is printing `Blob {size: 23, type: "text/plain"}`. The backend is printing:

```
{}
{ fieldname: 'upl',
  originalname: 'blobby.txt',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  destination: '/var/www/test/public/uploads/',
  filename: 'dc56f94d7ae90853021ab7d2931ad636',
  path: '/var/www/test/public/uploads/dc56f94d7ae90853021ab7d2931ad636',
  size: 23 }
```

Maybe also try it with a hard-coded Blob like in this example for debugging purposes.

Comment: I tried with hard-code huge blobe and it worked like a charm! thanks

Comment: i am trying the same code with canvas.toBlob and passing blob as parameter to callback but i am not getting anything on server

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use multer. Just use `express.raw()` inside `app.post()`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')); // for serving the HTML file

app.post('/api/test', express.raw({type: "*/*"}), function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   // do stuff with file
});

app.listen(3000);
```