# Uploading a blob with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Im struggling with uploading my pdf file to my server with nodejs help.

My code:

```
app.post("/sendFile", function(req, res) {
   var stream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.body.name + ".pdf"));
    stream.once('open', function () {
       stream.write(req.body.file);
       stream.end();
   });
});
```

However, the file which is being uploaded, is a `Blob`. Nodejs docs say that `.write` function accepts `<string> | <Buffer> | <Uint8Array>` as the first argument. Will it acept also a `Blob`? If not, which other function should I use to properly upload a `Blob` into my server?

Thank you.

Edit: or maybe I should change `Blob` into something else?

Comment: @JC97 I dont want to encode my `Blob` into base64. It will be an overkill (hundreds of bits which need to be stored somewhere)

Comment: It appears you might be using [`express`](http://expressjs.com). If so, are you using [`multer`](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) to process the upload?

Comment: @JasonCust I edited my post, thats all I have there. Should I include `multer`? Will it help me?

Comment: May be it is resolved in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677993/send-blob-data-to-node-using-fetch-multer-express/74396725#74396725

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is very easy to do with the multer module for Express.
We'll also add a test .html file to the directory (client side JavaScript).

To test this out, run node server.js, then navigate to http://localhost:8081 in your browser.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.post('/post_pdf/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST /post_pdf/');
    console.log('Files: ', req.files);
    fs.writeFile(req.files[0].originalname, req.files[0].buffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('ok');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script>

            var fileData = null;

            function loadFile() {
                var preview = document.querySelector('file');
                var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
                var reader  = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    fileData = file;
                }
                if (file) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            }

            function uploadFile() {
                data = new FormData();
                data.append('file', fileData);

                $.ajax({
                  url: "/post_pdf/",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: data,
                  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Result: Upload successful';
                  },
                  error: function(e) {
                      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Result: Error occurred: ' + e.message;
                  }
                });
            }

      </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" onchange="loadFile()"><br>
<button onclick="uploadFile()">Upload..</button>
<div id='result'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I dont really need the stream? I've heard its a better option to use streams to upload files. Or nope?

Comment: With multer you have the choice, and yes, I would say if the PDF is very large, a stream is a better option. I suspect in a lot of cases just buffering the data is fine!

Comment: What do you mean with 'very large'? Should I limit the file size for user? Like max 10mb?

Comment: I'd guess files of a few mbs should be fine to buffer and send, if they are maybe tens of megs it might be better to use streams. I'd suggest you test both, see what the performance of each is. The code is very much the same.

Comment: @Patrickkx Synchronously writing a file as shown in the example is a bit of a concern since this appears to be a web service. Because JavaScript is single threaded, using I/O events (writing the file in this case) synchronously will prevent this process from being able to handle any other concurrent requests. If you are only running one instance of this service to handle all of your requests, that means any other request would not be processed until the file was uploaded. This may not be a concern if your traffic is relatively low but you should be aware of it.

Comment: Good point @Jason, we can use an async write easily enough, though as you say it depends on the expected volume of requests.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the useful feedback of @JasonCust. This will improve performance of the upload process.

Comment: That `streaming_client.js` file is client or server side?

Comment: Oh, client side, you should not need to change the server side code.

Comment: Can I use `fs` on client side?

Comment: Anyways, what is `req.files[0].buffer`? Where did u declare `files` on client side? What is the `buffer`?

Comment: Certainly, if you are using Node.js as the client. You could use some other technology of course.

Comment: req.files[0] is the first file to be uploaded. The filename is passed as the first arg. to the script on the client.

Comment: So I've updated to use ajax on the client side.. I've also updated the server side code to serve the index.html file.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. It makes a lot of sense for me now. However, I would really like to use streams instead, since there can be multiple users which will like to upload file on my site. But still, thanks so much.

Comment: I can't see where's the blob file after conversion in server.js. Can someone please help?

Comment: It should be in the same directory as the server. js script. If not, perhaps we're seeing an error, which should appear in the console.