# How can I save ImageData as a PNG in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

In the browser, I was building an array of image data and as you can see here, converted it to quite a few different forms in order to download it in the browser, which worked:

```
let clamped = Uint8ClampedArray.from(frameBuffer);
let imageData = new ImageData(clamped, width, height);
this.resultContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
this.uri = this.resultCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
this.blob = dataURItoBlob(this.uri);
```

But now I'm trying to save this blob with the Node.js fs module, and this doesnt work:

```
fs.writeFile(this.path + "/" + angle + ".png", this.blob, err => {
  if (err) {
    alert("An error ocurred creating the file " + err.message);
  }
  console.log("The file has been successfully saved");
});
```

Edit: dataURItoBlob:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
  var byteString;
  if (dataURI.split(",")[0].indexOf("base64") >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
  else byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI
    .split(",")[0]
    .split(":")[1]
    .split(";")[0];
  // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
  var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
}
```

It's not throwing an error but the resulting file is invalid. How can I fix this?

Comment: How is `dataURItoBlob` implemented? Oh if it's [this](https://gist.github.com/davoclavo/4424731) that's not going to work. [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) does not accept [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), only [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) or strings.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-uri-to-buffer but the resulting image is just black. Before with the browser based method it was saving successfully so I can verify the data source is fine.

Comment: fyi, you can get a blob directly from the canvas with `canvas.toBlob` though unlike `canvas.toDataURL` it takes a callback that receives the blob

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677993/send-blob-data-to-node-using-fetch-multer-express

Comment: @gman not really. In electron, the same executing context has access to both the canvas and node modules like `fs`.

Comment: This question's title is how to save in node.js, not how to save in electron which is a different question. Maybe the question should be edited if it's about electron and not node.js. If the question is how to save a blob in electron there is already a Q&A for that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562192/write-file-to-disk-from-blob-in-electron-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this works

```
canvas.toBlob(saveBlob);

function saveBlob(blob) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    fs.writeFile('filename.png', new Uint8Array(reader.result), err => {
      if (err) {
        alert("An error ocurred creating the file " + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("The file has been successfully saved");
      }
    });
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

note in 2019 I might switch to promises and async stuff. There's little bit of setup but then usage is easier for some definition of easier

```
const fs = require('fs');  // would prefer import
const util = require('util');

const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

function readBlobAsUint8Array(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      return new Uint8Array(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
}

function getCanvasAsBlob(canvas) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     canvas.toBlob(resolve);
  });
}

async function saveCanvasAsPNG(filename, canvas) {
  const blob = await getCanvasAsBlob(canvas);
  const data = await readBlobAsUint8Array(blob);
  await writeFile(filename, data);
}
```

which can be called from another async function like

```
async function someFunc() {
  try {
    await saveCanvasAsPNG('foo.png', canvas);
    console.log('success');
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

or from a non-async function as

```
saveCanvasAsPng('foo.png', canvas)
  .then(() => {
     console.log('success');
  })
  .catch(alert);
```

note this also works

```
const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
const uu = dataUrl.substring('data:image/png;base64,'.length);
fs.writeFileSync(filename, uu, 'base64');
```

Comment: This is saving the string `[object ArrayBuffer]` to the file. I can see the array buffer contains the correct data, but the string output label of the object is being saved to the file for some reason with that code

Comment: @Viziionary "for some reason" is the same reason I already pointed out. `fs.writeFile()` does not accept anything but a `Buffer` or a string. If it is anything else, it will coerce it to a string.

Comment: fixed. @PatrickRoberts, `fs.writeFile` takes a `TypedArray` just fine. What it doesn't take is an `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes I did, but you said it only takes a Buffer or a String. It also takes a TypedArray